# Java application vs web service vs web application

Tags: java, web-services

I am developing a multi-platform (Android, iPhone, Windows and Blacbberry) mobile application. The application needs to communicate with our server for several tasks, such as retrieving buddy lists etc. The server interacts with data that is stored in a MySQL database. I intend to code the server element in Java, however I am confused by all the different types. So far, I think I have narrowed it down to three options:

1) I code the application using Jetty to accept http posts. I post XML to the server, handle it, interact with the DB and post a XML response back. I would save the application as a jar and leave it running on my server.

2)I develop a Java web service. REST/JSON/SOAP?

3)I develop a Java web application.

Whilst there are many questions already out there asking what the differences is, I am struggling to find a clear explanation as to what is the best approach in which situation. I have previously used the first approach but am assuming the second approach is the better option, I'm just not sure what the advantage is.

Comment: Why not have a RESTful API that can serve your content in both JSON and XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 1-3 options are all variants of a "Web application".

Jetty is a Java based http server/servlet container.  If you want to communicate between client and server using http, you are using an http server (although not necessarily Jetty).

A Web Service is part of a web application that conforms to a standard around how clients communicate with the server, and how the server offers up information to the clients.

A web application is a Java application that makes it services available over http.

So if you want to have your clients communicate with a server, and store info in a db, you are using a web-application.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I am still a little unsure. So are you saying my method of making a jar (with Jetty etc in) and running it on my server is the best option to go with?

Comment: it is one option.  You can use any number of servlet containers; I would just use tomcat.

Comment: By servlet container, do you mean the way its compiled? Would the tomcat be instead of the jar?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with option 2 as it is more lightweight and can be parsed directly in you're web application. XML got more overhead and must be translated, while you can just serialize objects directly to JSON from you're Java application and then parse them in javascript at frontend